# Weird inverse smiley effect on new voting buttons in some browsers

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, voting

The new voting buttons don't look right in all browsers. There are two funny little dots that make them look like smileys. And the smileys have the opposite meaning to what the buttons are used for!

[image]

The dots don't show up in IE or FireFox, but they do in Opera. May depend on versions etc but please can it be implemented in a way that works universally?

Comment: To be exact, [here is the list of supported browsers on SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported).

Comment: @HomegrownTomato to be sure, there is no "code universally", but there can be "works universally", no? Anyway, as you're probably aware, Opera effectively split into different "streams" when it [evolved in directions not liked by all, removing functionality that for some was the reason for using Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Opera_web_browser). So there will be a variety of versions in use. I use the latest version in the v.12 stream, which is 12.17.

Comment: For readers: Mobile version of latest opera doesn't have this issue only the desktop version and that too may be old versions.

Answer (score 3):

This is a visual issue effecting an unsupported browser (12.17 was released in April 2014, over a year ago - only to fix the heartbleed issue, so the actual rendering engine has not been updated for longer than that).

As such, we will not be fixing it - we need to dedicate our time to items of high impact. This issue effects a very small number of users who choose to use an obsolete browser, and only visually so.

This issue is likely a bug in the browser itself (Opera is well known to have quirks no other browser has when it comes to interpreting CSS - I am talking about the versions of Opera the predate the move to webkit, such as this one).